# OOP: Get variable of class1 defined by construct from class2 (extending class1)

Tags: php, oop

I have the following classes. What I want is to define just one time, in the main class ( **class1** ) a variable via *construct()* and then recall that variable from other classes those extends class1.

**Class1**:

```
<?php

class Class1 {

    protected $var1;

    public function __construct( $var1 = '' ) {

        if ( !empty($var1) ) $this->var1 = $var1;

    }

    public function get_var() {

        return $this->var1;

    }

}
```

**Class2**:

```
<?php
class Class2 extends Class1 {}
```

**Index**:

```
<?php
require 'class1.php';

$class1 = new Class1( 'test' );
echo 'Class1: ' . $class1->get_var();

require 'class2.php';

$class2 = new Class2();
echo '<br>Class2: ' . $class2->get_var();
```

The result here is that the first Echo shows the correct value ( test ), but the second no, just an empty string.

So, there is a way to do this without define each time the variable in construct?

Comment: Class2 has its own constructor, even if you extend Class1. You need to implement Class2's constructor and call Class1's constructor via `::parent()`

Comment: @hasumedic that's what i thought too after first read, but the "problem" here is just that $class1 and $class2 are two distinct object instance. no way that $class2 will have same $var1 variable content as $class1...

Comment: Indeed. Two different instances of a class are not going to share the same attributes unless if they are actually instantiated with the same attributes. So, at the end of the day, OP will need to implement a constructor in Class2 that calls Class1's constructor and instantiate it with the same value.

Comment: Since you have two instances, each will have a value. If you want to have cross-instance values, you should take a look at [**static**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this idea with `static` so you can do like this:

```
<?php
class Class1 {

        protected static $var1;

        public function __construct( $var1 = '' ) {

            if ( !empty($var1) ) self::$var1 = $var1;

        }

        public function get_var() {

            return self::$var1;

        }

    }

    class Class2 extends Class1 {}

$class1 = new Class1( 'test' );
echo 'Class1: ' . $class1->get_var();


$class2 = new Class2();
echo '<br>Class2: ' . $class2->get_var();

?>
```

Comment: Totally disagree with your solution. You're using a static variable to bypass the scope problem. Static variable are not intended for this kind of purposes. I think giving an answer like this to a user that (it's clearly) learning the basics of the OOP will lead him to have a lot of problems dealing with more complex problems in the future.

Comment: @AndrewReborn sorry, you talk in general What is the specific problem in this answer, you didn't guide me until now

Comment: @GoudaElalfy There are a lot of reasons why using static variables is, in the most of the cases, wrong. For the OOP principles, the data must be encapsulated inside the object. With your answer, you are actually using the static variable to bypass the scope (and in consequence, the encapsulation) of the state variable $var1.

Comment: I know it's wrong, but at least it works. I prefere this instead of rewriting each time the variable, 'cause it will be used from other people who don't know the meaning of $db ( or worse still define again the construct )

Answer (score -1):

Check your code carefully: Class2 extends the superclass Class1. Class1 has, in its own constructor, the $var1 parameter that is assigned to the status variable $var1 (that has the access set to protected).

When the subclass (Class2 in your case) is called, nothing is passed to its own constructor. Additionally, you didn't define any constructor in your Class2 code. You can do something like this:

```
class Class2 extends Class1 {
    public function __construct($var1 = '') {
        parent::__construct($var1);
    }
}
```

What's happening here? You are actually overriding the __construct method. Without calling the superclass's method __construct with the parent::__construct, only the Class2 defined method will be executed. parent::{method_name} will make you able to call the Class1 construct method inside your overridden method (in this case, you're extending the __construct functionalities).

When you'll instance Class2, pass a string to the constructor and the status variable $var1 will be valorized. Remember that extending a class you inherit all its properties and methods.

Comment: In PHP, " Parent constructors are not called implicitly **if** the child class defines a constructor" ([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)). So if the child class doesn't define a constructor, the constructor of the parent **is** called. This means in this very specific case a constructor in Class2 is not needed. Just call `$class2 = new Class2('value');`

Comment: I have never said anything about the implicit / explicit call of the constructor. If you carefully read my answer, I say "you're actually overriding the __construct method". When I say that nothing is passed to the constructor of the class2 is just that, in his code, this is the statement: $class2 = new Class2(); and in fact nothing is passed. I just wanted to give him a more complex overview on the situation and the opportunities he has with the override of the methods.

Answer (score -1):

This example works fine.

If the purpose is to use the class1 instantiated and class2 have those properties. In case a new property is needed also for class2, a new class1 can be reserved with a different property as follows:

```
<?php

class Class1 {

    protected static $var1;

    public function __construct( $var1 = '' ) {

        if ( !empty($var1) ) self::$var1 = $var1;

    }

    public function get_var() {

        return self::$var1;

    }

}

    class Class2 extends Class1 {}

    $class1 = new Class1( 'test' );
    echo 'Class1: ' . $class1->get_var() . "\n";

    $class2 = new Class2();
    echo 'Class2: ' . $class2->get_var() . "\n";

    $class1 = new Class1( 'prod' );
    echo 'Class1: ' . $class1->get_var() . "\n";

    $class2 = new Class2();
    echo 'Class2: ' . $class2->get_var() . "\n";

?>
```

Output:

> Class1: test
>
> Class2: test
>
> Class1: prod
>
> Class2: prod

Comment: This is basically the same answer as the one given by @GoudaElalfy, but with output... And with 25 mins in between.. seems legit. (BTW, not my downvote). Edit: and you didn't even say what you changed and why.

Comment: Please check the updated reply, I just tested the code and provide prove for  static variable in class inheritance.